# How to call a specialized struct template without providing the chevron info?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, constructor

To be my question more clear, firstly I show you my templated struct `State` to describe the state vector of a [state space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation) according to the dimension :

```
template<unsigned int Dimension>
struct State;

// Specialization : for dimension 1
template<>
struct State<1>
{
    State() = default;
    State(double x) : x{ x } {}

    double x{};
};

// Specialization : for dimension 2
template<>
struct State<2>
{
    State() = default;
    State(double x, double dx) : x{ x }, dx{ dx } {}

    double x{};
    double dx{};
};

// Specialization : for dimension 3
template<>
struct State<3>
{
    State() = default;
    State(double x, double dx, double ddx) : x{ x }, dx{ dx }, ddx{ ddx } {}

    double x{};
    double dx{};
    double ddx{};
};
```

By this way, I can build a `state` variable with the 3 dimensions :

- 1 dimension : `auto state = State<1>(2.0);`
- 2 dimensions : `auto state = State<2>(2.0, 4.7);`
- 3 dimensions : `auto state = State<3>(2.0, 4.7, 5.9);`

**But I am wondering :**

Can I define the variable state without providing the dimension value in chevron, but only with the compile to deduce it from the number of value I provide in the constructor. Such as :

```
// What i would like to be able to do
auto state = State{2.0, 4.7}; // FAILED ( 2 values provided, so I would like the compilator to deduce it's the constructor of State<2> )
// Instead of doing
auto state = State<2>{2.0, 4.7};
```

Thanks you for your help !

Answer (score 6):

Simply add a [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides):

```
template<class... Ts>
State(Ts...) -> State<sizeof...(Ts)>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bfafc7vva)

Before C++17, a typical solution was to introduce a helper function:

```
template<class... Ts>
State<sizeof...(Ts)> makeState(Ts... values) {
    return State<sizeof...(Ts)>(values...);
}
```